# Editing status and %done of issue page in Redmine

Tags: redmine, percentage, status, issue-tracking

I have been working on editing the status bar of the issue page. On that page the %done ratio changes according to the status.

1. If % Done is made "0 %", Status should be defaulted to "New".
2. If % Done is made greater than "0 %" and less than "100 %", Status should be defaulted to "In Progress".
3. If % Done is made "100 %", Status should be defaulted to "Complete".
4. If Status is made "New", % Done should be defaulted to "0 %".
5. If Status is made "In Progress", errorcheck % Done cannot be '0 %" or "100 %".
6. If Status is made "Complete", % Done should be defaulted to "100 %".

In which way I need to approach to be done with this requirement?

Thanking you

Comment: Use a if-else or case statement?

Answer (score 3):

You should first select the appropriate task done ratio calculation method. Your requirements imply that you have to select "Use the Task Status" option in "Administration" - "Settings" - "Task Tracking".

[image]

Then you define the status done ratios in "Administration" - "Settings" - "Task Statuses" separately for each status.

[image]

The %Done ratio can't be the trigger for status changes. Status changes do trigger the ratio changes. Additionally, if you've choosen the "Use the Task Status" method in "Task Tracking" settings, your users won't be able to select the status done ratio.